# How to get Image.Source as string

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[It's easy to set a source for an image in Xamarin](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.Image):

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
Image image = new Image;
image.Source = "someImage.jpg";
```

But I can not do the reverse operation.
ex: given an image with its source already set, print the source.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Print Image source ==> {0}",image.Source);
Console.WriteLine ("Print Image source ==> {0}",image.Source.ToString());
```

...
and a few more incoherent combinations.

Could anyone tell me how to get the source (with a string) from an image.

Comment: What is `Image`, and in what way is reading the property not working?  I also see you're setting it with `source` and reading it with `Source` - are they actually separate properties, or is this a typo, in which case, can you show the code you've actually attempted to compile?

Comment: The first snippet won't work either. Assuming you're talking about System.Drawing.Image, there's no public `source` property. BCL public member names never start with lowercase anyway.

Comment: @Asad: notice the xamarin tag. http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.Image

Comment: There are a few `Image` types in C#. which one are you talking about?

Comment: `Image` is an abstract class. Do you mean `Bitmap`?

Comment: Like the others said: show your actual code (you're using `source` and `Source` where you mean the latter) and explain what is not working.

Comment: sorry for the typo (source => Source), I have reedited. the Image is from the Xamarin.Forms package. And what is not working, it's when I am trying to read image.Source, I can not get anything. I would expect to be able to get the Source that has been previously set as a string. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The **Xamarin.Forms** **Image.Source** property is of type **ImageSource**.

**ImageSource** in **Xamarin.Forms** has a few classes that inherit this class such as:-

- FileImageSource
- StreamImageSource
- UriImageSource

You can **type check** the **Image.Source** to see what implementation is being used in **Image.Source**, and then **cast it**, and access the properties of the **casted object**.

For instance (assuming **ImageSource** is a **FileImageSource**) you will have something like:-

```
Xamarin.Forms.Image objImage;
..
..

..
if (objImage.Source is Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)
{
    Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource objFileImageSource = (Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)objImage.Source;
    //
    // Access the file that was specified:-
    string strFileName = objFileImageSource.File;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Xamarin.Forms.Image` has a `Source` property of type `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource` which has an implicit cast from `string`.  That's why you can do `Image.Source = "someImage.jpg"`, but it does not have a way to go back, likely because it only uses the string to find the file and load it.  If you need the name of the file you loaded you'll have to keep track of it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void myImage_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var url = ((sender as Image).Source as UriImageSource).Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new WebView_Page(url));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //await DisplayAlert("!", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
```

or use it like

```
var url = (myImage.Source as UriImageSource).Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).